# Adding/using Attributes for ASP.Net controls

Tags: asp.net, attributes

I was wondering where can we get a list of attributes that we can add to an ASP.NET control.
An example is the following block of code from :

```
protected void Grid1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
      ((CheckBox)item["TestColumn"].Controls[0]).Attributes.Add("onClick","javascript:hi();");
    }
}
```

The following code couldn't work which I figure could be due to 'onClick' not applicable to Checkbox ASP.NET control.

Hence, is there a place we can refer to for attributes where we can add to each ASP.NET control? And also for the following code:

```
Attributes["click"] = abc();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes must be added on RowCreated event of GridView. Please check below.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs
e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{

// Dummy Code
Button btnButton =
(Button)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("btnButton");
btnButton.Attributes.Add("onmouseover",
"this.className='actionH'");

}
}
```

Comment: Ok. But how do we know which attributes we can use for each control? Thanks.